What is type of dynamic page props in nextjs app
I want to add a type for my dynamic route that I can replace with type "any" in code bellow written with Typescript .
export default async function DetailProduct({ params }: any) {
    const { imageAddress, title, price } = await getProductByID(params.id);

    return ...
}

Does nextjs have a type for it ? I use nextjs14

NextJS does not have a type for it. But hey, you can define the type according to your usage of keys right. If you are simply using the string id from params, just define the types as below:
export default async function DetailProduct({ params }:{ params : { id : string } } ) {
    const { imageAddress, title, price } = await getProductByID(params.id);

    return ...
}


Example from docs

yes its true but i think there is defined type for this ,thanks

You define your own types either at the call or you can create an definition
You don't need the await part you can just extract the id from the param object.
export default function Product({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
const { id } = params;
return (
    <>
        <div>Product ID: {id}</div>
    </>
)}

interface IProduct = {
  imageAddress: string; 
  title: string;
  price: number;
}


export default function Product({ params }: { params: IProduct }) {
...

Source https://raynoppe.com/snippets/nextjs-app-router/app-structure-in-next-js/page-component/
